# Contador de ocorrência de palavras em arquivo txt em C

Tags: c, c++

Eu estou tentando fazer um programa em C que leia um arquivo-texto e grave em outro arquivo uma estatística de palavras. Cada palavra lida, deverá ser inserida em uma lista, sem repetição. Cada nó dessa estrutura deve ter um contador de ocorrência. No arquivo de saída a sequência de palavras deverá em ordem decrescente de ocorrências.
Fiz um programa base que deveria ler e inserir na lista, porém não esta funcionando. Queria ajuda por favor.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>


//Declaração da estrutura usada no programa.

typedef struct palavras{

    char palavra[100];

    int quantidade;

    struct palavras *prox;

}palavras;

int main(){

    //Variaveis
    palavras *primeiro=NULL, *aux=NULL, *percorre=NULL;
    char string[100], ch[0];
    int total=0;
    //Abrindo o arquivo
    FILE* arquivo = fopen("teste.txt", "r");
    if(arquivo == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro ao abrir o arquivo.txt.");
        return 1;
    }
    //Lendo a primeira palavra do arquivo
    while(1){
        strcat(string,ch);
        ch[0]= fgetc(arquivo);
        if(ch[0]==' '||ch[0]=='\n'||ch[0]=='\t')
            break;
    }
    printf("%s",string);
    //Guardando a primeira palavra em um nó de uma lista encadeada.
    primeiro= (palavras*)malloc(sizeof(palavras));
    strcpy(primeiro->palavra,string);
    primeiro->quantidade=0;
    primeiro->prox=NULL;
    //
    while(!feof(arquivo)){
        if((ch[0]==' ')||(ch[0]=='\n')||(ch[0]=='\t')){
            for(percorre=primeiro; percorre!=NULL; percorre=percorre->prox){
                if(strcmp(string,percorre->palavra)==0){
                    percorre->quantidade++;
                    strcpy(string,"");
                    break;
                }
                if(percorre->prox==NULL && strcmp(string,"")!=0){
                    aux= primeiro;
                    primeiro= (palavras*)malloc(sizeof(palavras));
                    primeiro->quantidade= 1;
                    strcpy(primeiro->palavra, string);
                    primeiro->prox= aux;
                    strcpy(string,"");
                }
            }
        }else{
            strcat(string,ch);
        }
        ch[0]= getc(arquivo);
    }
    //
    for (percorre=primeiro; percorre!=NULL; percorre= percorre->prox){
        total= total + percorre->quantidade;
        printf("%s - %d\n", percorre->palavra, percorre->quantidade);
    }
    //
    printf("\nO texto cont%cm %d palavras.\n", 130,total);
    fclose(arquivo); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro está a dar erro de segmentation fault porque o vetor do caratér tem que ter comprimento de 2. Depois podemos ordenar comparando a quantidade e trocando as variáveis e por fim trocar para ordem decrescente.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

//Declaração da estrutura usada no programa.

typedef struct palavras{

    char palavra[100];

    int quantidade;

    struct palavras *prox;

} palavras;

int main(){
    //Variaveis
    palavras *primeiro=NULL, *aux=NULL, *percorre=NULL;
    char string[100], ch[2];
    int total=0;
    //Abrindo o arquivo
    FILE* arquivo = fopen("teste.txt", "r");
    if(arquivo == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro ao abrir o arquivo.txt.");
        return 1;
    }
    //Lendo a primeira palavra do arquivo
    while(1){
        strcat(string,ch);
        ch[0]= fgetc(arquivo);
        if(ch[0]==' '||ch[0]=='\n'||ch[0]=='\t')
            break;
    }
    printf("%s",string);
    //Guardando a primeira palavra em um nó de uma lista encadeada.
    primeiro= (palavras*)malloc(sizeof(palavras));
    strcpy(primeiro->palavra,string);
    primeiro->quantidade=0;
    primeiro->prox=NULL;
    //
    while(!feof(arquivo)){
        if((ch[0]==' ')||(ch[0]=='\n')||(ch[0]=='\t')){
            for(percorre=primeiro; percorre!=NULL; percorre=percorre->prox){
                if(strcmp(string,percorre->palavra)==0){
                    percorre->quantidade++;
                    strcpy(string,"");
                    break;
                }
                if(percorre->prox==NULL && strcmp(string,"")!=0){
                    aux= primeiro;
                    primeiro= (palavras*)malloc(sizeof(palavras));
                    primeiro->quantidade= 1;
                    strcpy(primeiro->palavra, string);
                    primeiro->prox= aux;
                    strcpy(string,"");
                }
            }
        }else{
            strcat(string,ch);
        }
        ch[0]= getc(arquivo);
    }
    // Ordenar
    struct palavras *node=NULL, *temp = NULL;
    int temp_qtt;
    char temp_palavra[100];
    node = primeiro;
    while(node != NULL) {
        temp=node; 
        while (temp->prox !=NULL) {
            if(temp->quantidade > temp->prox->quantidade){
                temp_qtt = temp->quantidade;
                strcpy(temp_palavra, temp->palavra);
                temp->quantidade = temp->prox->quantidade;
                temp->prox->quantidade = temp_qtt;
                strcpy(temp->palavra, temp->prox->palavra);
                strcpy(temp->prox->palavra, temp_palavra);
            }
            temp = temp->prox;
        }
        node = node->prox;
    }

    // Trocar para ordem decresecente
    palavras* current = primeiro;
    palavras *prev = NULL, *next = NULL;

    while (current != NULL) {
        next = current->prox;
        current->prox = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    primeiro = prev;

    for (percorre=primeiro; percorre!=NULL; percorre= percorre->prox){
        total= total + percorre->quantidade;
        printf("%s - %d\n", percorre->palavra, percorre->quantidade);
    }
    //
    printf("\nO texto cont%cm %d palavras.\n", 130,total);
    fclose(arquivo); 
}
```